# How to enforce npm to use https node repository

Tags: node.js, npm, macos-mojave

Lately i've had a weird issue where a lot of my dependencies now just don' t retrieve from the https based repository anymore, i'm not sure what happened, i've checked my config, this is what is has in it:

```
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.com/"
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.com/"
; metrics-registry = null (overridden)
; registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/" (overridden)
```

I've downgrade to a few earlier versions and still no luck, thinking that a newer version is what's causing the issue, based on what I'd read here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20434

I'd like to find out why this issue is happening and if other's are having similar issue and also how do i force npm to always use SSL based registry for retrieving dependencies.

Comment: delete `~/.npmrc` and do a fresh reinstall, it should use the default registry which is on https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved a similar issue with:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm install
```

Comment: I tried that, it added an additional entry of ```registry = "https://registry.npmjs.com/"``` to the config file, similar to what I posed in above and still didn't work.

Comment: Update: There was a caching issue with the local npm registry, which was refusing to update to https, also I updated npm and re-installed all dependencies too. Seems to work for now, not sure if that was the root cause or not though...